# DevExpress.XtraGrid.StyleFormatCondition using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

How can i format some cell value into something else using **DevExpress.XtraGrid.StyleFormatCondition** . For example I need to bold some value in one or more cell with same value and **how to change only one column not entire row**

Here it is my example:

```
         For i As Integer = 0 To GridView1.DataRowCount
                Dim a As String = (GridView1.Columns(0)).ToString

                If a = "Vrsta računa" Then        'THE NAME OF COLUMN
                    Dim b = GridView1.GetRowCellValue(i, "accountsType")  ' THE NAME OF CELL

                    If b = "KLASA" Then                   

                        Dim condition1 As StyleFormatCondition = New  DevExpress.XtraGrid.StyleFormatCondition()
                        condition1.Appearance.BorderColor = Color.Blue
                        condition1.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Red
                        condition1.Appearance.Options.UseBackColor = True
                        condition1.Appearance.Options.UseBorderColor = True

                           '***** HOW TO BOLD CELL VALUE *******

                        condition1.Condition = FormatConditionEnum.Expression
                        condition1.ApplyToRow = False
                        condition1.Expression = "[accountsType] = 'KLASA'"      
                        GridView1.FormatConditions.Add(condition1)

                    ElseIf b = "SINTETIKA" Then

                        Dim condition1 As StyleFormatCondition = New DevExpress.XtraGrid.StyleFormatCondition()
                        condition1.Appearance.BorderColor = Color.Blue
                        condition1.Appearance.BackColor = Color.HotPink
                        condition1.Appearance.Options.UseBackColor = True
                        condition1.Appearance.Options.UseBorderColor = True
                        condition1.Condition = FormatConditionEnum.Expression
                        condition1.ApplyToRow = False
                        condition1.Expression = "[accountsType] = 'SINTETIKA'"

                        ' I WANT TO Have an effect on a cell , AND not on entire row

                        GridView1.FormatConditions.Add(condition1)

                    ElseIf b = "ANALITIKA" Then

                        Dim condition1 As StyleFormatCondition = New DevExpress.XtraGrid.StyleFormatCondition()
                        condition1.Appearance.BorderColor = Color.Blue
                        condition1.Appearance.BackColor = Color.Green
                        condition1.Appearance.Options.UseBackColor = True
                        condition1.Appearance.Options.UseBorderColor = True
                        condition1.Condition = FormatConditionEnum.Expression
                        condition1.ApplyToRow = False
                        condition1.Expression = "[accountsType] = 'ANALITIKA'"
                        GridView1.FormatConditions.Add(condition1)

                    End If
                End If
            Next
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using Format Conditions not in a correct way. 
There is no need to traverse through all rows and columns manually.  Before painting each row, GridView automatically checks if it meets any condition in its FormatConditions collection. If so, GridView applies a corresponding style.

Please refer to the following help topic to learn how to use Format Conditions correctly:

https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument759